# сайт "дергается" при загрузке

Tags: html, css

здравствуйте, есть сайт с контейнером, внутри него content с `float: left` и с правой стороны nav с `float: right` вообщем стандартная схема

но дело в том что когда в контенте много блоков с новостями, при загрузки сайта, навигационное меню справа загружается не сразу а с небольшой задержкой (после того как прогрузился content), и получается что оно выводится не большим рывком а это выглядит не очень красиво

что можно предпринять в данной ситуации?

Comment: Приведите пример, хотя бы ссылку на ресурс. Так это можно гадать долго.

Comment: @WkorniilowGg неа, ссылка на ресурс не годится — вскоре после ответа на этом ресурсе будет уже другой код, так что вопрос потеряет смысл.

Comment: Иван, пожалуйста добавьте в вопрос код, воспроизводящий проблему или хотя бы дающий примерное представление. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, жмите [edit]. Тут есть сниппеты, кнопка `<>` в режиме редактирования, это аналог jsfiddle, но встроенный прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавить прелоадер на сайт. Чтобы он загрузил весь скрипт и потом показал сайт

Comment: Ответы должны быть развёрнутыми, а не содержать только лишь короткие советы или ссылки. Попробуйте дать больше деталей, написать пример.